# execution reverted: DepositContract: reconstructed DepositData does not match supplied deposit_data_root

Tags: contract-deployment, testnets, medalla, goerli

I am getting this error when deploying Goerli's Medalla Beacon Contract through Remix.

```
execution reverted: DepositContract: reconstructed DepositData does not match supplied deposit_data_root
```

input (web3)

```
pubkey: 0x94a61e90d697a287c31d389d2389aff2523a3e677949810381f3e485d79eb07150463f2c2b2796f744874e4810e3e778
withdrawal_credentials: 0x0045fe3422a0c68e6192a3782850334ed9fe162212a9f888c31aaa67c8d34e7b
signature: 0x81c0e6d9953ba76c1d0c27162e98576019e702fd94b27269791fcf30d0afc371acc9385444cfe82dbc2b50612b1ae20416d17fa1360151209a09d66f5b615f84f0a701fe60d668d0ef4fabcb815c4fe95855c242edaa02bf5f5f9a3d7b7cc87f
deposit_data_root: 0x2467b379933a366aa89584578cfd63434769a07bec11a347a207f70862fa1a92
```

The tx: https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0x2f9118dafa84846768dcac5d66fea223729bbc22799e787f511774dfe437d211

Contract: https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x07b39f4fde4a38bace212b546dac87c58dfe3fdc#code

Any idea? thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you should investigate the problem:

1. Go to [the contract's code](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x07b39f4fde4a38bace212b546dac87c58dfe3fdc#code)
2. Search for the error-message `DepositContract: reconstructed DepositData does not match supplied deposit_data_root`
3. Find it in function `function deposit`:

```
// Verify computed and expected deposit data roots match
require(node == deposit_data_root, "DepositContract: reconstructed DepositData does not match supplied deposit_data_root");
```

4. You know what `deposit_data_root` is (since you provided it as input), so scroll up a bit to see how `node` is computed:

```
bytes32 node = sha256(abi.encodePacked(
    sha256(abi.encodePacked(pubkey_root, withdrawal_credentials)),
    sha256(abi.encodePacked(amount, bytes24(0), signature_root))
));
```

5. You know what `pubkey_root`, `withdrawal_credentials` and `signature_root` are (since you provided each one of them as input), so scroll up a bit to see how `amount` is computed:

```
uint deposit_amount = msg.value / GWEI;
```

6. If all the input values stated in your question are correct, then the problem is in `amount`, in which case, the reason for the problem is that you passed an incorrect `msg.value` (i.e., you passed an incorrect amount of ether when you executed the transaction)

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion. I was able to figure it out that I passed wrong amount number to eth2.0-deposit-cli. That was why the contract couldn't reconstruct DepositData.